# Saving additional attributes in a join table for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Using Rails 4.

```
# premedication.rb
class Premedication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :premedication_dosages
  has_many :patients, through: :premedication_dosages
end

# patient.rb
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :premedication_dosages
  has_many :premedications, through: :premedication_dosages
end

# premedication_dosage.rb
class PremedicationDosage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :premedication
end

# patients_controller.rb
def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit(
    premedication_ids: [],
  )
end

# premedication_dosages join table
class CreatePremedicationDosage < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :premedication_dosages do |t|
      t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
      t.belongs_to :premedication, index: true
      t.integer :dosage
    end
  end
end

# _form.html.erb
<%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :premedication %><br>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :premedication_ids, Premedication.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <div class="collection-check-box">
      <%= b.check_box %>
      <%= b.label %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now the above works fine by storing the `premedication_id` and `patient_id` in the `premedication_dosages` table, but there is a column in `premedication_dosages` called `dosage` which I want to store a value. The end result I want in `premedication_dosages` table is:

```
premedication_id: 1
patient_id: 1
dosage: 10
```

How should the text field for `dosage` be included in the form?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
# patient.rb
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :premedication_dosages
  has_many :premedications, through: :premedication_dosages

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :premedication_dosages
end


def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit(premedication_dosages_attributes: [:dosage, :premedication])
end
```

This will mean you'll have to change your form structure:

```
#app/conntrollers/patients_controller.rb
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @premedication = Premedication.all
      @patient = Patient.new
      @patient.premedication_dosages.build
   end
end

<%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :premedication_dosages do |d| %>
     <%= f.collection_select :premedication, @premedications, :id, :name %>
     <%= f.number_field :dosage %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, this will only allow you to add a single `premedication_dosage`, which means you'll have to use something like [`Cocoon`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to add more dynamically.

I can write about `cocoon` if you want, it would take some time, so I'll leave it until you let me know whether the above is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Rich Peck, but I need it to be a checkbox, where it can be a multi selection, and each selection accepts `dosage` value (if selected).